# HTML : align td in the center of next tr

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

I am creating HTML Emailer. 
I want to have the td elements to be center in the next tr. if there is 1 td element then it should be center of tr , if there is 2 td elements then also it should be in the center of tr and if there is 3 td elements then it should be in the center of tr. 
How can I do so? 
I can't use any external CSS or library as I am making HTML Emailer. 
I have used the below code.

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="background:white; text-align:center; margin: 0 auto !important; padding: 0px; width:600px !important; line-height: 100% !important; border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;font-family:Arial" >
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td >
        <table style="width:450px;margin:0 auto;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
            
              <td align="center">
                <table style="margin:0 15px;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="middle">
                        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LVHwl97.png" style="padding-right:5px;" alt="" width="18" height="18">
                      </td>
                      <td style="border-left:thin black solid; padding:0 0 0 10px;text-align:left;">
                        
                        <span style="margin:0;font-size:11px;">element 1 
                        </span>
                      </td>

                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
              
              <td align="center">
                <table style="margin:0 15px;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="middle">
                        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LVHwl97.png" style="padding-right:5px;" alt="" width="18" height="18">
                      </td>
                      <td style="border-left:thin black solid; padding:0 0 0 10px;text-align:left;">
                        
                        <span style="margin:0;font-size:11px;">element 1 
                        </span>
                      </td>

                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td><td align="center">
                <table style="margin:0 15px;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="middle">
                        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LVHwl97.png" style="padding-right:5px;" alt="" width="18" height="18">
                      </td>
                      <td style="border-left:thin black solid; padding:0 0 0 10px;text-align:left;">
                        
                        <span style="margin:0;font-size:11px;">element 1 
                        </span>
                      </td>

                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td><td align="center">
                <table style="margin:0 15px;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="middle">
                        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LVHwl97.png" style="padding-right:5px;" alt="" width="18" height="18">
                      </td>
                      <td style="border-left:thin black solid; padding:0 0 0 10px;text-align:left;">
                        
                        <span style="margin:0;font-size:11px;">element 1 
                        </span>
                      </td>

                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
            
              
              
              <td align="center">
                <table style="margin:0 15px;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="middle">
                        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LVHwl97.png" style="padding-right:5px;" alt="" width="18" height="18">
                      </td>
                      <td style="border-left:thin black solid; padding:0 0 0 10px;text-align:left;">
                        
                        <span style="margin:0;font-size:11px;">element 1 
                        </span>
                      </td>

                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td><td align="center">
                <table style="margin:0 15px;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="middle">
                        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LVHwl97.png" style="padding-right:5px;" alt="" width="18" height="18">
                      </td>
                      <td style="border-left:thin black solid; padding:0 0 0 10px;text-align:left;">
                        
                        <span style="margin:0;font-size:11px;">element 1 
                        </span>
                      </td>

                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td><td align="center">
                <table style="margin:0 15px;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="middle">
                        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LVHwl97.png" style="padding-right:5px;" alt="" width="18" height="18">
                      </td>
                      <td style="border-left:thin black solid; padding:0 0 0 10px;text-align:left;">
                        
                        <span style="margin:0;font-size:11px;">element 1 
                        </span>
                      </td>

                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: You want vertical align or horizontal align?

Comment: horizontal align

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get what you want. But I think you are looking for `colspan`.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Element 1</td>
        <td>Element 2</td>
        <td>Element 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center">Centered</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Working with `colspan` and `rowspan` should also make those nested tables a little more manageable.

Comment: the data will be fetched from database . I don't know how many data will be there

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear about what you want to do but if you want a pure HTML one then,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td align="right">Right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td align="center">Centered</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td align="left">left</td>
    </tr>  
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Another example with `colspan`,

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr style="text-align:center">
      <td>Month</td>
      <td>Savings</td>
      <td>Gone</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr style="text-align:center;">
            <td>
              test
            </td>
            <td>
              test2
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `td` won't content will.

Comment: See the code snippet. Even in your code the `td` content is aligned.

Comment: Great man. but I do not this is what @rishi is looking for. Text will align, that's ok,

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me ,and also you need to be cautious when nesting tables. 
you can use 'colspan'

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of colspan and text-align: center. Just remember that if a column has less than the maximum number of TDs in it, then colspan must be set to that. So below the columns with one and two TDs are set to 3 to line up with the one with three. I put the two TDs in an individual table which is also another techniques you can use to have different TDs in a TR. Note that the TD the table is in also has its colspan declared as 3 they must also be equal.

Think of it in an excel sheet, you have column a, b, c and so on. If you want a column to be the centre of three then it has to cross a, b and c.

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0"          border="1" style=" width:100%; text-align:center;">
 <tr>
   <td colspan="3">ipsum</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td colspan="3">
     <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0"  border="1" style=" width:100%; text-align:center;">
 <tr>
  <td>ipsum</td>
  <td>ipsum</td>
 </tr>
   </table>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>ipsum</td>
  <td>ipsum</td>
  <td>ipsum</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the hybrid approach. It requires more code than what you might be used to.

To see the code in action:

> *Run the code snippet*, do full screen and resize your browser.

Hybrid method of coding:
Hybrid coding uses outlook conditional statements to create the columns specifically for outlook while all other email clients read the div tags to create the columns.

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="600">
<![endif]-->
    <table class="container hundred" width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; max-width: 600px;">
 <tr>
   <!-- 5 column starts -->
   <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; font-size: 0px; padding: 0px;">
     <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
 <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
   <td align="left" valign="top" width="120">
 <![endif]-->
     <div style="width:20%;min-width:120px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
       <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td style="font-size:12px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000;">Column 1 of 5</td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     
     <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
 </td><td align="left" valign="top" width="120">
 <![endif]-->
     
     <div style="width:20%;min-width:120px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
       <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td style="font-size:12px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000;">Column 2 of 5</td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
 </td><td align="left" valign="top" width="120">
 <![endif]-->
     
     <div style="width:20%;min-width:120px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
       <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td style="font-size:12px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000;">Column 3 of 5</td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
 </td><td align="left" valign="top" width="120">
 <![endif]-->
     
     <div style="width:20%;min-width:120px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
       <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td style="font-size:12px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000;">Column 4 of 5</td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
 </td><td align="left" valign="top" width="120">
 <![endif]-->
     
     <div style="width:20%;min-width:120px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
       <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td style="font-size:12px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000;">Column 5 of 5</td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
     
     
     <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <![endif]-->
     </td>
   <!-- 5 column ends -->
   </tr>
</table>

    
 <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this is the answer you were looking for.

Cheers